# Software for coloring geometric patterns

Tags: color, software-recommendation, patterns

I am trying to colour geometrical patterns similar to the one attached here. Any suggestions which software I can use for this purpose?

I am making these patterns in Geogebra and it offers to export them in vector and other picture formats e.g. jpg, png etc. Question is these patterns have repeated units so i am looking for software that can help me to color them quickly and efficiently.

I have seen people using Illustrator for this, but I'm looking for a free software. I use Windows.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE!

Comment: I think you want to explain your needs a bit better. Allmost any graphic application could do this well.

Comment: Thank you the replies. I am making these patterns in Geogebra and it offers to export them in vector and other picture formats e.g. jpg, png etc. I have seen youtube videos in which artists are using Illustrator for this but in that case pattern was also made in the same software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The free and open source vector image editor Inkscape might work for you, however it's not particularly easy software and there is a learning curve, but Illustrator is similar in that respect.

In Inkscape a little setting up would be required.  In the example below I used an SVG that I downloaded.  The pattern itself is on one layer which I locked in the layers panel. Then I made a new layer for the fills underneath. Then I used the Fill Bounded Areas tool (aka Bucket Fill tool) to fill it with colours.

You could also unlock the pattern layer, select shapes and change the stroke colours as required in the Fill and Stroke panel.  You can also apply fill colours directly in this way.

[image]

Other possibilities include free and open source raster image editors such as GIMP or Krita. Both have a Bucket Fill tool that can be used similarly.  Both GIMP and Krita can open SVGs, but they will be rasterized. Use Inkscape if you want keep everything vector. Inkscape is like Illustrator. GIMP and Krita are more like Photoshop.

Note: I have no affiliation with any of the software listed above. These are merely suggestions.  All three I have suggested have fairly large user communities, plus a plethora of tutorials available on youtube if you need to learn more.